# React-native .map() arround an object in my state

Tags: android, ios, react-native, array.prototype.map

I have a state with an object of days :

```
this.state = {

schedule: { monday: "", tuesday: ""}

}
```

i set this state with data form firebase like that:

```
 schedule :  { monday: userData.monday, tuesday: userData.tuesday}
```

userData is also an object :

```
{ start:"",
  end: ""
 }
```

I want to display all the days of the state ans every "start", "end" of this day.
I can display the days :

```
   renderScheduleDay(){
    return Object.keys(this.state.schedule)

         .map((schedule, key) => (
          <View key={key}>
            <CheckBox
              title={schedule}
              containerStyle={styles.containerStyle}
              checked
            />

      <Text>{?????}</Text> 
          </View>
        ));

}
```

But how to display each "start" and "end" nested in days ??

Comment: `this.state.schedule[schedule]['start']` and `this.state.schedule[schedule]['end']` if I understood you correctly

Comment: @bennygenel That's work ! thx a lot ;)